# How can I get the name of a country in its language abbreviation in Android?

Tags: android

I have abbreviations for each language such as jpn, eng, ind, kor, etc.

Can you tell me the name of the country with this?

What is the best way to check each one with a switch statement?

Comment: Languages are used by more than one country. For example, if "eng" is English, English is [the primary language in many countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_where_English_is_an_official_language), including Australia, Canada, the United Kingdom, and the United States.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a premade JSON response something like this [JSON list of all countries](https://github.com/samayo/country-json/blob/master/src/country-by-abbreviation.json) and then create a data class .. Use that data class to find the abbreviation or vice versa.